# Cant call PDFtk from Matlab, but can from terminal

Tags: macos, bash, matlab, terminal, pdftk

For some reason, when I try to call PDFtk from Matlab (`pdftk *.pdf cat output combFile.pdf`), I get a `/bin/bash: pdftk: command not found` error, but I can run the same command in terminal in the same directory with no problem. I have restarted my system, but that did not seem to help. I am running `Mac OSX 10.9.1` and `Matlab 2013b`. I do not want to use the absolute path to PDFtk, because it needs to be cross-platform compatible.

EDIT: This may help. When I echo $PATH in Matlab I get `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. When I do it in terminal, I get `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`. Then I did `which pdftk`and it returned `/usr/local/bin/pdftk` Is there anyway to add the `/usr/local/bin/` path to Matlab?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to call PDFtk from Matlab?

Comment: Sure, it is `system('pdftk myfig[0-9][0-9].pdf cat output myfigCombined.pdf');`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the export PATH idea would probably be better for a single system (note: I have not tested it), but I needed my script to be used on several Mac and Linux machines that are out of my control. This is what I ended up using (yes, I know that this will break on Windows, but that is ok)

```
if(ismac)
    system('/usr/local/bin/pdftk myfig[0-9][0-9].pdf cat output myfigCombined.pdf');
else
    system('/usr/bin/pdftk myfig[0-9][0-9].pdf cat output myfigCombined.pdf');
end
```

Originally, I was using `if(isunix)` for the second command, but presumably because of Mac's unix architecture both commands were being executed.

EDIT: I was able to test it on Linux and it worked perfectly. I suppose this would be the syntax for Windows, but I do not have access to a Windows machine with PDFtk and Matlab installed, so no guarantees (also, I am not sure that I did the path quotation marks right...):

```
elseif (ispc)
    system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk" myfig[0-9][0-9].pdf cat output myfigCombined.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your $PATH environment variable is not exported to Matlab. Reading
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255609
I'd suggest to add a

```
export PATH=$PATH:<Path-to-your-PDFtk-binary>
```

in your .bash_profile

Comment: It should be put in `MATLAB/bin/matlab` according to the link. Clearly it is getting loaded in the bash startup files (unless it's aliased or something weird) as he got it to execute from shell.

Comment: I think this would probably work, but this script will need to run on at least 4 computers (Mac and Linux) that are out of my control. I also thought about specifying the full path, but it is different for Mac (/usr/local/bin) and Linux (/usr/bin).